# could not be established. Broker may not be available for kafka UI and broker

Tags: apache-kafka, bitnami-kafka, provectuslabs-kafka-ui

I am trying to create a kafka cluster using bitnami kafka image and kafka UI with following file. When I use the network mode host, kafka UI can access kafka-broker and everything works however when I use bridge network the UI is not getting connected to the broker.

```
version: "3"
services:
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: docker.io/provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:9094
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: 'true'
    networks:
      - app-tier

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka-single-broker
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9094:9094'
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID: 0
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: controller,broker
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 0@kafka:9093
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: 'yes'  # Enable KRaft mode
    networks:
      - app-tier

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

I know the fix requires some sort of change in lister configuration. Thanks for the help. Also I am using KRAFT instead of zookeeper

```
Error:
024-03-03 18:59:37,708 WARN  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] Connection to node -1 (kafka/127.0.1.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-03-03 18:59:38,711 INFO  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-03-03 18:59:38,711 WARN  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] Connection to node -1 (kafka/127.0.1.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-03-03 18:59:39,714 INFO  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-03-03 18:59:39,714 WARN  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1709492351-18] Connection to node -1 (kafka/127.0.1.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I ran the podman-compose and two containers are getting created. I should have been able to see the online cluster on kafka-ui but the cluster is showing offline.
[New docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrmaN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconfiguration. In `kafka` you define listeners for external traffic to listen on localhost only.

```
KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
```

Use `kafka` service name here and it will work:

```
KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://kafka:9094
```

Comment: [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1709674327-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1709674327-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/127.0.1.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Hi, it is still giving me the issue. why it is trying to connect to localhost instead of kafka

Comment: How did you start the containers after the file change? Did you run: `docker compose down && docker compose up`?

Comment: yes. I wrote a complete a different yaml file. and I ran the commands.

Comment: Interesting. It is working on my machine. However, I'm using `docker compose` and you are using podman. Can you use `docker compose` to see if that is not a problem with podman? You can also drop all `kafka` like this `EXTERNAL://kafka:9094` -> `EXTERNAL://:9094`. You can reference my [docker compose](https://github.com/BartMiki/composer/blob/main/kafka-stack/compose.yml) that deploys UI and Kafka

Comment: Hi, it worked. now I can see the single broker in kafka ui when I used docker instead of Podman.

Comment: I faced issue with your provided docker-compose, I solved it using "true" instead of true for   DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: "true" in kafka ui configuration.